# Arbitrary intersection of open sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

As I was reading metric spaces in brief (as a prerequisite to point-set topology), I came across a seemingly important proposition to the definition of open sets. The proposition states, in simple words that,

```
"the arbitrary union and the finite intersection of open sets in a metric space is open".
```

Comparing this to the definition of topology, which includes the condition that the arbitrary union and the finite intersection of sets in a topology must belong to the topology, seems to hint that topology deals a whole lot with open sets.

However, why is an arbitrary intersection of open sets not always open? (I am familiar with a few famous examples of infinite intersections of open sets being closed but I'm looking for a formal proof)

Comment: The examples you know are a formal proof that the general statement is false.

Comment: "However, why is an arbitrary intersection of open sets not always open? (I am familiar with a few famous examples of infinite intersections of open sets being closed but I'm looking for a formal proof)"

Those "examples" *ARE* the proof. Anything that is wrong once can never be true always.

Comment: "I am familiar with a few famous examples of infinite intersections of open sets being closed"  It should also be mentioned that being closed does not always imply non-open.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the arbitrary intersection of open is open in every topological space. The real numbers with its usual topology is a topological space. But $\bigcap\{(-1/2^n,1/2^n):n\in\mathbb Z^+\}=\{0\}$ is not open, a contradiction.

However, maybe you wanted a proof that every topological space has a collection of open sets whose intersection is not open? That's also not possible: a discrete topology where every set is open is a counter example. More broadly, the class of [Alexandrov spaces](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000090) all have the property that arbitrary intersections of open sets are open.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a formal way to understand that the given statement is false without the use of any examples, let's first understand the proof of the result "**Finite intersection of open sets is open**".

**Open Set:** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $A \subset X$. $A$ is said to be open if $\forall x \in A, \exists r>0 \,such \,that\, B_d(x, r) \subset A$.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $\{G_i : 1≤i≤n \}$ be a finite collection of open sets. We claim that $G=\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}G_i$ is open. Let's take an arbitrary element $x \in G$, hence $\forall 1≤i≤n, x\in G_i$. Since $\forall 1≤i≤n, G_i$ is open, $\forall 1≤i≤n, \exists r_i >0 \, such \, that \, B_d(x, r_i) \subset G_i$ Choose $r=min\{r_i : 1≤i≤n \}$. Hence $\forall 1≤i≤n, B_d(x, r) \subset G_i$ and hence $B_d(x, r) \subset G$. Therefore finite intersection of open sets is open.

Similarly, let's try to prove arbitrary intersection and identify where the problem arises.

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Let $\{G_i :i \in I\}$ be a collection of open sets. We try to prove $G=\bigcap_{i \in I} G_i$ is open. Let's take an arbitrary element $x \in G$, therefore $\forall i \in I, x \in G_i$. Since $i \in I, G_i$ are open, $\exists r_i>0, B_d(x, r_i) \subset G_i$. We need a radius $r$ that works for all $G_i$. If suppose, we choose $r=min\{r_i :i \in I\}$, we can't guarantee that $r>0$. In the finite case, we had only finite number of radii, hence we can guarantee that minimum exists and is positive. But in arbitrary case, we can't guarantee for the existence of such $r>0$. Hence arbitrary intersection of open sets need not be open.

Hope my argument is correct!! Any correction is always welcome...